# php client send binary data to CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I've googled alot for this but unfortunately I found nothing close to what I'm looking for.

My idea is to have a plain PHP standalone client to send an Excel 2003 file (binary) to a controller of my CakePHP project. This is what i need to figure out how it is theoretically working.

Any helpful idea would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,
Marius

Comment: That's a little broad, isn't it? I mean, that client could be anything, and sending data can be done 1001 ways... What exactly do you mean by "client", and what is the actual programming related problem that you're facing?

Comment: i just want to understand the theory behind it, there is no documentation within CakePHP how to send binary content to their HTTP adapter to ANY controller... at least not that I know of. Their HTTP adapter chapter is just very high-level

Comment: Yeah, but without knowing what exactly you're trying to do, it's pretty hard to give you any advice. From your description I could only guess that you're talking about making HTTP requests to a CakePHP application via a vanilla PHP script (I don't really get what "HTTP adapter" you're talking about). But then I'd still don't know what to answer you, as there's nothing special about making HTTP requests in PHP, and I don't want to waste my time with writing down things that possibly won't help.